# Métonymie « du déterminé » ou « de destination » : « région gourmande » et productivité du phénomène ?

Tags: vocabulaire, linguistique, évolution, figure-de-style

On trouve au TLF une référence à une « métonymie du déterminé » :

> ♦ [P. méton. du déterminé] Où l'on mange bien. *Région gourmande*. *Il
> suffirait, à un gastronome, de dire que Saulieu, patrie gourmande de
> l'illustre Alexandre Dumaine est en Morvan* (*Arts et loisirs*, 3 mai
> 1967, p. 75).
>
> [ Trésor informatisé de la langue française, « [gourmand](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gourmand) » ]

Au Wiktionnaire on parle plutôt d'une « métonymie de destination » :

> [...]
> 6. Apprécié des gourmands ou des gourmets. Note : Par métonymie de destination. <sup>[1](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gourmand#reference-1)</sup>
> *Région **gourmande***. [...]
>
> [ Wiktionnaire, « [gourmand](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gourmand#Adjectif) » ]

S'agit-il de synonymes ou est-ce qu'un des deux termes est consacré ? Peut-on expliquer en quoi cette métonymie consiste dans *région gourmande* ? Est-ce similaire à [*bureau*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/bureau) ? Ce genre de métonymie est-il un phénomène relativement très productif ou non dans l'évolution ou glissement du sens des mots ?

Answer (score 1):

Je crois que vous êtes victime d'une appréhension complètement fausse des termes que vous analysez et essayez de comprendre. J'ai essayé de clarifier tout cela par un diagramme.

[image]

Il n'est aucunement question de métonymie en ce qui concerne le mot « gourmand » ; « gourmand » ne signifie toujours que « qui se laisse aller à un certain excès dans sa soif de plaisir » ; il n'est pas détourné de son sens premier.

---

*Précisions*

1/ Le sens du mot « région » devient « les habitants de la région ».
2/ En ce qui concerne  le mot « bureau » il s'agit du même type de métonymie :  la pièce contenant les bureaucrates devient un contenu particulier, c'est à dire les personnes qui y travaillent.
 3/ Dans le sens présent (région gourmande) le mot gourmand a un sens atténué et déplacé si on se réfère au sens vieilli (TLFi,  ,,Qui mange avec avidité et avec excès``) et ce serait plutôt (TLFi) « Qui aime la bonne nourriture et qui sait l'apprécier » ou plus spécifiquement, (TLFi) « où on mange bien » mais ces particularités de la psychologie d'un individu sont toujours plus ou moins accompagnées d'une tendance à l'excès, c'est ce que je voulais dire, on ne peut en aucun cas parler d'ascétisme.